# Owncloud showing error for some packages ever after installing

Tags: php, owncloud

I installed owncloud and tried on the browser it shows the following errors.
I installed all packages and restarted the server still it is showing the same.

```
PHP module dom not installed.
Please ask your server administrator to install the module.

PHP module XMLWriter not installed.
Please ask your server administrator to install the module.

PHP module XMLReader not installed.
Please ask your server administrator to install the module.

PHP module libxml not installed.
Please ask your server administrator to install the module.

PHP module SimpleXML not installed.
Please ask your server administrator to install the module.
```

PHP modules have been installed, but they are still listed as missing?
Please ask your server administrator to restart the web server.

Comment: Are the modules loaded? Check with php.ini (or phpinfo();). Maybe you installed the packages for a wrong php version if you run multiple php versions on your server?

Answer (score 0):

as of PHP `7.x` you might need to:

```
sudo phpenmod <module name>
```

which merely just writes an `.ini` file, which instructs the server to load the module.

they're not enabled by default anymore.